# How to model a specific optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, constraint-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have a specific problem and don't know how to change it to a feasibility or optimization problem. Can anyone please help me?

Assume that the objective function is Obj=f(x,y). We want to see for which value of x , the minimum value of Obj=f(x,y) is greater than 2 for all possible values of y. In addition y is a variable that depends on x with some constraint and has many allowable values for each x. If we make constrain on f(x,y) >2, the result of f(x,y) may be a value of x,y such that the value of f(x,y) is >2 but we miss those x such that the minimum value of f(x,y) is greater than 2 for all values of y.

This simple problem has camped in my mind for several weeks!!

Comment: Could you please provide more information for your problem? How does your function look like? What kind of variables do you use?

Comment: The objective function is a simple summation of a set of variables taking the value of 0 or 1.  There are a set of variables taking the values of 0 or 1 with some constraints. I need to find the best values of variables such that the minimum value of the objective function (The summation of a specific set of variables) is greater than 2.

Comment: The requirement that the objective function is greater than 2 can be modeled as a constraint. And you want to minimize the objective function, right?

Comment: No, that is different. I want to find the values of variables such that the after minimizing the objective function, it is greater than 2. A simple if clause can word such that:                                                                                                                                                         if (minimize f(x,y,z)>2) then output "x,y,z".  However I don't know any solver that support if statement and minimize function together.

Comment: I'm not sure if we have the same understanding of minimizing a function. Because what you wrote implies to me that I have to provide argument values to get the minimum of a function. So minimize f(1) might be a different value than minimize f(2). But to me minimizing a function f means finding an argument x, s.t. f(x)<=f(y) for all values y of the domain. Therefore I would first minimize f with a solver and then check whether f(x_min) is > 2. Maybe you could provide a small toy example to make your problem a bit clearer?

Comment: Thanks, assume the simple example s.t   Obj=f(x,y). We want to see for which value of x , the minimum value of Obj=f(x,y) is greater than 2 for all y. If we make constrain on f(x,y) >2, the result of f(x,y) may be a value of x,y such that the value of f(x,y) is >2 but we miss those x such that the minimum value of f(x,y) is greater than 2 for all values of y.

Comment: Would the following produce the correct result? Enumerate all values for x. Let x' be such a value. Minimize f(x', y) with respect to y, subject to the given constraints, using a solver. Let y_min be a minimum found by the solver. If f(x', y_min) > 2, add x' to the result set R.

Comment: A single x is enough. I don't want all the x that satisfy the f(x,y) is >2. However which solver supports this statement?

Comment: I cannot test each x by myself, I need the solver to test each x and find the best result.

Comment: I think I understand what you need, but right now I don't have an answer. You could use heuristic optimization, but this wouldn't give you the optimal solution of course...